# how to detect my browser busy or waiting state using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to detect my browser is in waiting state or busy state using Jquery and to implement a loader also. I already used code in below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sync_bills.php",
        success: function(resp) {
            $("#results").html(resp);
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div id="results"><img src="images/loading.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Loading..." /></div>
```

Comment: ahm what did you will to find out? maybe asynchron and synchron mechanismus could be a lookup-hint for you

Comment: what's wrong with the code provided? What's the expected behaviour? Please could you elaborate further?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things in jquery ajax `beforeSend` and `complete`

make changes to your code like this

```
$(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sync_bills.php",
    beforeSend : function(){
        $("#loader").show();
    },
    success: function(resp) {
        $("#results").html(resp);
    },
   complete: function(resp) {
        $("#loader").hide();
    },
  });
 });
```

this works for me if i need loader

Comment: In the OP code the `success` callback already overwrites the loader image, so it should not be necessary to hide the loader on complete (maybe on `error`)

Comment: yeah..but if its success not executed then also complete will work